# How can I use my enum in QString.arg()?

Tags: c++, qt, enums, string-formatting, qstring

My enum is declared as `Q_ENUM` macro so it print the enum field's name when using with `qDebug()` (as I'm using QT 5.5) instead of its value. I'd like to do the same with `QString().arg()` so I declared that same enum with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` macro but it didn't work either and give the below error.

**Code:**

```
qDebug() << QString("s = %1").arg(myClass::myEnum::ok);
```

**error:**

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'QString::arg(myClass::myEnum)'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q_ENUM does not provide a direct conversion to some kind of string value, so you would have to use QMetaEnum:

`qDebug() << QStringLiteral("s = %1").arg(QMetaEnum::fromType<MyClass::Priority>().valueToKey(static_cast<int>(myClass::myEnum::ok));`

static_cast is of course necessary for enum class.

Comment: I was in fact looking for a way to make `arg()` know about my enum class type and do the conversion all internal, without the need to convert the enum field to its key value myself, just like current `qDebug()` do.

Comment: Take a look here: http://woboq.com/blog/q_enum.html
I don't think theres another way, except from contributing an overloaded version of arg() to Qt's source code

Comment: I've read it and got as new `qDebug()` works for pretty-printing for enums but can I extend `qarg()` like he did with `qDebug()`?

Comment: Hm, well look at my comment, I've edited it shortly after writing it. You could probably write a (templated?) function that takes enums declared Q_ENUM and converts them to QString or char* or whatever, but another overload of `arg()` would be only possible by contributing to Qt.

Comment: ok then, thanks. I'll write this overload and if worth contribute to QT

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following [conversion helper](http://woboq.com/blog/q_enum.html):

```
template <typename T>
typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<QtPrivate::IsQEnumHelper<T>::Value , QString>::Type
toString(T enumValue)
{
   auto mo = qt_getEnumMetaObject(enumValue);
   auto enumIdx = mo->indexOfEnumerator(qt_getEnumName(enumValue));
   return QLatin1String(mo->enumerator(enumIdx).valueToKey(enumValue));
}
```

Then it becomes a simple matter:

```
qDebug() << QString::fromLatin1("s = %1").arg(toString(myClass::myEnum::ok));
```

Comment: Good approach, I ended up writing something like this. Here's mine (http://pastebin.com/78EzkfaZ). But what I really wanted was extend `arg()` someway so that it does this internally. I'll follow marius_linux and try to write a overload for `arg()` method. It's pretty useful.