# Printing a Qt property enum value as a key string

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML `Loader` and on some event I want to print its `status` property, but I'm getting `0` on the console, even if I use `toString()`. So I need to always refer to the order of the enum values in qquickloader_p.h to know what's going on.

Any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a way to get the enum key without knowing or even passing the enum name, if the following syntax suits your needs:

```
Info.print(loader, "status")
```

You can get it via this:

```
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QMetaProperty>
#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class EnumInfo : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public slots:
    void print(QObject * obj, QString prop) {
      const QMetaObject * meta = obj->metaObject();
      int i = meta->indexOfProperty(qUtf8Printable(prop));
      if (i > -1) {
        QMetaProperty p = meta->property(i);
        if (p.isEnumType()) {
          QMetaEnum en = p.enumerator();
          qDebug() << en.name() << ":" << en.key(obj->property(p.name()).toInt());
        }
      }
    }
};
```

That object is best exposed to QML as a singleton, although for more casual use a context property won't be too much overhead.

Comment: It is more generic to make it `Q_INVOKABLE` simple member function and return `QString`.

Comment: @Orient I don't think there is much of a difference. Both cause the function to get moc treatment. I prefer `public slots` because I can put a bunch of function afterwards, instead of having to keep typing `Q_INVOKABLE`. The question was about printing, so its printing, which is optimal in the context of the OP, `Info.print(loader, "status")` is much better than `console.log(Info.print(loader, "status"))`. If a string needs to be returned, the modification is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way would be to access that property from a C++ helper that looks up the enum's name using the metadata generated by moc. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661752/1329652).

Answer (score 0):

ENUMs are used to make code more readable compared to the use of integers but faster than using strings for that purpose.
Their intent is mainly comparison.

If you want to have the names to it, you need to create additional structures (e.g. arrays) to look them up. Usually this is not necessary, so it is more efficient, not to do it.

If you look at `console.log(typeof(Loader.Ready))` you will find, that the `ENUM` is indeed nothing more than a `number` - and maybe some meta object information.

Due to the MetaObject, there is a way, even though uncomfortable... The thing is, you need to know the name of the `ENUM`

**enumspy.h**

```
#ifndef ENUMSPY_H
#define ENUMSPY_H

#include <QObject>

class EnumSpy: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    EnumSpy(QObject* parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    QString getEnumName(QObject* object, QString name, int index) const;
};

#endif // ENUMSPY_H
```

**enumspy.cpp**

```
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QDebug>
#include "enumspy.h"

EnumSpy::EnumSpy(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{

}

QString EnumSpy::getEnumName(QObject *object, QString name, int index) const
{
    const QMetaObject* meta = object->metaObject();
    QMetaEnum enm = meta->enumerator(meta->indexOfEnumerator(&name.toStdString()[0]));
    qDebug() << meta;
    return QString(enm.key(index));
}
```

Register it, create an object, and call the method.

> **Note:** The name for the ENUMs of the Loader is `Status`
>   `myEnumSpy.getEnumName(myLoaderInstance, 'Status', 1) => "Ready"`

Comment: If you don't know the name of the `ENUM` maybe you can return a list of all tuples `(ENUM, key)`.

Comment: I'd suggest to not be an exemplary boy scout and split code into h and cpp for such short answers. Code is more illustrative when it is more concise and compact.

Comment: @dtech, if I'd knew how to do that, I would save me that work. However I started really learning C++ just 3 weeks ago, so forgive me my lack of knowledge. I once was googleing, how to have it in one file, and the answer I found was: "Don't do it!". So I figured, it won't have priority to learn that ;-)

Comment: That's definitely recommended practice in production, but brevity and clarity outta take precedence in a QA scenario. I mean the important stuff is like 4 lines of code, no need to spread that to an entire page :)